# Renombrar etiqueta asp-net-5 por asp.net-5, asp.net-core

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Hay una errata en la etiqueta [asp-net-5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-net-5) porque no está siguiendo el mismo formato que es resto de etiquetas de ASP.NET (el guión entre `asp` y `net`. El nombre correcto debería ser [asp.net-5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-5)

Por otro lado, este nombre está en desuso porque ahora el nombre oficial es ASP.NET Core y por lo tanto la etiqueta correcta debería ser [asp.net-core](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core), quizás lo adecuado sería renombarla ya directamente con este nombre o mantener las dos como sinónimos.

En el sitio en inglés ya están usando la etiqueta [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-core/info) cuya descripción se podría traducir para la nuestra *(a ver si saco un rato para hacerlo)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambio realizado. Puedes verificar los resultados.

Comment: Comprobado, por cierto la etiqueta antigua ¿se podría modificar para cambiar el primer "-" por un "."? Saludos

Comment: La etiqueta antigua desapareció y está como sinónimo